# Renaming a class results in an error from sfdx packaging 2

Tags: salesforcedx, package

I've built a managed package using SFDX and the new packaging features. I recently did some refactoring on a public class in the package (note: public, not global) which included giving it a better name.

Now, when I try to upload a new package version with

```
sfdx force:package:version:create -x -p "My Name" -w 20
```

I (eventually) get the response:

> ERROR:  Manifest validation exception for ApexClass, missing
>   [SendGridPersonalizations].

Where `SendGridPersonalizations` is the old name of the class.

I've had problems with sfdx's local files getting out-of-sync when pushing/pulling and before, so I tried my go-to-solution for that: removing the .sfdx directory, then doing a forced push and pull. That didn't help.

Have I missed something? Surely renaming an internal class inside a package should be OK?

Comment: It's not documented as such, so I'm not sure there's a way to do this in the source control side. Have you tried renaming it in a scratch org?

Comment: When I say I renamed it, I used Illuminated Cloud to refactor it. Which just does standard operations. To rename A to B, it copies A with the new name of B. Updates all code references to B, deletes A, then pushes the result via sfdx. So my guess is that there may be some dangling reference left in the package description. I assume the packaging system does some metadata analysis (certainly traditional packaging does) and that might have gone wrong?